# Variation problem : Euler equation using direct method

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider a map $I : C^1[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$I (f)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}(f'(x))^2 -V(f(x))dx$$
where $V(t)\leq 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is smooth. Let $\Gamma=\{f\in C^1[0,1]|\| f\|_{\infty}\leq 1\}$.
Show that: there exists $u\in \Gamma$ s.t.
$$I(u)=\inf\limits_{f\in \Gamma}I(f)$$
By definition of $\inf$, and $V\leq 0$,
there exists $\{u_n\}$ is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded, by Arzela Ascoli's Theorem, there is a subsequence $u_{n_k}$ converge uniformly on $[0,1]$,
also, $u$ is continuous.

Moreover, $u_{n_k}$ is bounded in $H^1(0,1)$
$$u_{n_k}\rightarrow u \mbox{ weakly on $H^1(0,1)$}$$
$$u_{n_k} \rightarrow u \mbox{ uniformly on $[0,1]$}$$
My question is "How to show that $u\in \Gamma$ ?"

"Do we need to add more assumption on $V$ ? or adjust the admissible set ?"

Comment: You don't need more assumptions on $V$; what you have is enough. Begin by showing that $u$ satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation in a weak form; the regularity of minimizers is based on that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But why will $u$ satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation ? Do you mean that we first work on a weaker admissible set then apply the Euler-Lagrange equation and use the regularity to smooth up the function ?